# R: closure can't find object until called

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, closures, higher-order-functions

I have a problem with a higher order function in R:

```
power <- function(x , modify){
  return(
      function(y){
         return(  modify( y^x ) )
      }
  )
}

mod <- function(z){z+1}

sq <- power(x = 2,modify =  mod  )

# remove the function that was passed to `power()`, I expect it to be saved in the function environment:

rm(mod)

sq(2)
# Error in sq(2) : object 'mod' not found
```

However, if I call `sq()` in some way before removing `mod()`, the problem does not occur, but I get the warning `"In sq(2) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation"`:

```
mod <- function(z){z+1}
sq(2)
rm(mod)
sq(2)
```

How can I avoid having to call the closure with the `mod()` being defined in the global environment before using the closure in a new context? And what is going on here in terms of scoping and promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modify` is a promise that isn't evaluated until the function is called. You can use `force` to evaluate formal arguments.

```
power <- function(x , modify){
  force(modify)
  return(
      function(y){
         return(  modify( y^x ) )
      }
  )
}
mod <- function(z){z+1}
sq <- power(x = 2,modify =  mod  )
rm(mod)
sq(2)
# [1] 5
```

Note from `?force` that you don't actually need to use `force`. You can simply evaluate the symbol to get the same effect.

```
power <- function(x , modify){
  modify
  return(
      function(y){
         return(  modify( y^x ) )
      }
  )
}
mod <- function(z){z+1}
sq <- power(x = 2,modify =  mod  )
rm(mod)
sq(2)
```

Comment: @DavidHeckmann: Any object passed to a function as a formal argument behaves that way, not just other functions. Look at the examples in `?force`.